# how to download file from file's path stored in MySql by using servlet,JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, download

i want to download my file from file's path stored in Mysql by using JSP,actually i did it, **but when download a file, it only has a file size= 0 KB**, here is my code to download:

```
package rizki;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet(name = "downloadServlet2", urlPatterns = {"/downloadServlet2"})
public class downloadServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

     static ResultSet result;
    static Connection con;
    static PreparedStatement stat;
        static Statement st, st2;
        private static String dataSourceName="odbcMySql";
    private static String dbURL="jdbc:odbc:"+dataSourceName;
    private static String dbUser="root";
    private static String dbPass="085219236994";



    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            String id=request.getParameter("file_id");
            String filePath="";
            String fileName="";
            String completeFile="";
            String sql="select FileName,lokasi from savedFile where id= ?";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);
          stat=con.prepareStatement(sql);
          stat.setString(1, id);
          result=stat.executeQuery();
          if (result.next()) 
            {

                fileName = result.getString(1);
                filePath=result.getString(2);

            }
      completeFile=filePath+File.separator+fileName;
        File downloadFile = new File(completeFile);
         int length   = 0;

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        // gets MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(completeFile);
        if (mimeType == null) {        
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

        // modifies response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

        // forces download
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(downloadFile));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        //int bytesRead = -1;

      while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1))
        {
            outStream.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        in.close();
        outStream.close(); 


        }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

and this my code for **storing file's path into** database and **copying file** to C:\Users\KikiRizki\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BLH\build\web\folderFile

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>

<%@ include file="koneksiDB.jsp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <%
    try
    {
        String files="";
        String fileName="";


        File savedFile=null;
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        // Check that we have a file upload request
        if(!isMultipart)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            //ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            List items = null;

            try
            {
             items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            }
            catch (FileUploadException Ex)
            {

            Ex.getMessage();
            }

            Iterator itr = items.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext())
            {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
                if (item.isFormField())
                {
                    String name = item.getFieldName();
                    String value = item.getString();

                    if (name.equals("files"))
                    {
                       files=value;
                    }


                }

                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fileName = item.getName();
                        savedFile = new File (config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"\\folderFile\\"+fileName);
                        item.write(savedFile);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                      out.println("error "+ex.getMessage());

                    }

                }



            }
            try
            {

                //CallableStatement cs = koneksi.prepareCall("{call insertVideo2 (?,?)}");
                String st = "insert into savedFile(fileName,lokasi,uploader) values (?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement psmt=cn.prepareStatement(st);
                psmt.setString(1,fileName);
                psmt.setString(2,savedFile.getPath());
                psmt.setString(3, "ADMIN BLH");

                psmt.executeUpdate();

                psmt.close();
               cn.close();
                 out.println("upload success!");
                 out.println(" back to home");
            //st.executeUpdate("insert into video values ('"+VideoName+"')");
                ///response.sendRedirect("AdminVideo.jsp");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              out.println("Error "+ex.getMessage());

            }

        }


    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        out.println("error" +Ex.getMessage());
    }

    %>
    </body>
    <a href="index2.jsp">Home Page</a>
</html>
```

please help or correct if i'm wrong, i really appreciate your help, thank you very much

Comment: Except for the usage of the JDBC-ODBC driver, the usage of static fields instead of local variables, and the lack of correct JDBC resource handling, I don't see anything fundamentally wrong in the file-related code. What happens when debugging? Any error? Does the file exist?

Comment: there are no errors or exceptions any more, yes the file exist

Comment: So, when you step through the code using your debugger, do you see it enter inside the loop and write bytes to the response?

Comment: yes , i see it, when i upload my file, it will be copied to**C:\Users\KikiRizki\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BLH\build\web\folderFile\18667.JPG** and this file's path and will be stored in MySql

Comment: So, if you see the code write bytes to the response, how could the file have 0 byte? That contradicts what you're saying in your question. How do you see that the file has 0 byte?

Comment: when i click download, and try to open my file,the file is empty because the file has 0 byte, but when i open myfile in source folder the file has 1,221KB

Comment: When the file is zero size the process is opened a new descriptor for writing bu nothing has been written into it.

Comment: so how to fix it @RomanC?? i don't have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. return the input stream which file will be downloaded from direct database

--

```
public static InputStream getTheDbFileInputStreamWhereId(String id) {

    try {
        String sql = "select songFile from songs where id= ?";
        Connection con = getConnectionGp();
        PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stat.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            return result.getBinaryStream(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("prolbem in dao dwonload");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

2. make the road clear to download the file in the doGet method

--

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        String fileName = Dao.getFileNameWhereId(id);
        if (fileName == null) {
            System.out.println("file name not found!");
            return;
        }

        String resContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
        response.setContentType(resContentType);

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        InputStream in =  Dao.getTheDbFileInputStreamWhereId(id);

        if (in == null) {
            System.out.println("file not found according to id");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = in.read(); i != -1; i = in.read()) {
            out.write(i);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("problem occurs");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 package rizki;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



  @WebServlet(name = "downloadServlet2", urlPatterns = {"/downloadServlet2"})
  public class downloadServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

 static ResultSet result;
static Connection con;
static PreparedStatement stat;
    static Statement st, st2;
    private static String dataSourceName="odbcMySql";
private static String dbURL="jdbc:odbc:"+dataSourceName;
private static String dbUser="root";
private static String dbPass="085219236994";



protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String id=request.getParameter("file_id");
        String filePath="";
        String fileName="";
        String completeFile="";
        String sql="select FileName,lokasi from savedFile where id= ?";
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);
        stat=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stat.setString(1, id);
        result=stat.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) 
        {

            fileName = result.getString(1);
            filePath=result.getString(2);

        }
        completeFile=filePath+File.separator+fileName;
        File downloadFile = new File(completeFile);
        if(downloadFile.exists()){


            int length   = 0;


            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            // gets MIME type of the file
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(completeFile);
            if (mimeType == null) {        
                // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

            // modifies response
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

            // forces download
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
            //OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(downloadFile));
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            //int bytesRead = -1;

            int i;   
            while ((i=in.read()) != -1) {  
                out.write(i);   
            }  

            in.close();
            out.close(); 


        }else{
            System.out.println("File does not exist at location "+downloadFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
     }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Comment: Please check i have made a minor change.

Comment: If there isn't file on location it will be downloaded as **0 bytes** so  we have check whether file is exist or not

Comment: **completeFile=filePath+File.separator+fileName;** made this error  File does not exist at location C:\Users\KikiRizki\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BLH\build\web\folderFile\18667.JPG\18667.JPG , so when i use **File downloadFile = new File(filePath);** getWriter() has already been called for this response, but the file still have 0 bytes

Comment: ya that's true. my edit was just to check if file is exist or not.

Comment: but how can it be? downloadServlet2.java access the right file's path **C:\Users\KikiRizki\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BLH\build\web\folderFile\18667.JPG‌**

Comment: file:///C:/Users/KikiRizki/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BLH/build/web/folderFile/18667.JPG this file's path was given when i access the file from the source folder,

Comment: is it opening on browser.. if no then file is not there.. 
or there might be access issue please check whether your program can access your file

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to flush `outStream.flush();`

The code should be

```
  while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1))
    {
        outStream.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
        in.close();
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
```

`OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();` change it to `ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();`

Comment: there is no effect after i change it, file size is 0 Byte

Answer (score -1):

you can flush your `outStream.flush();`

change this ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream(); to OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

Comment: Nonsense. The `close()` already implicitly invokes `flush()`. The upcast can also impossibly solve OP's problem. OP's problem is caused elsewhere. There are way too much problems in the code snippet posted so far and OP seems to be not at all aware about the fact that his servlet code is not thread safe at all.